# How do i get custom metabox data from each multisite blog?

Tags: multisite, plugins

I wanted to create a Menu component in my site that shows links to the different sites in my network (WordPress Multisite).

My solution was to create a site_option using CMB2. Each site will fill that up with the necessary values which then will be used for the menu to be displayed on the theme's header.php. However, I am only getting the main/default site's site_option data despite using switch_to_blog().

Here's the code:

```
$sites = wp_get_sites();
$current_site = get_current_blog_id();

foreach ($sites as $site) {
  $details = get_blog_details($site['blog_id']);
  $zSite = $details->blog_id;
  $mycolor = '';
  $mclass = '';

    if( $current_site == $zSite ) {
        $mclass = 'active';
    }

    switch_to_blog( $site[ 'blog_id' ] );
        $mycolor = myPrefix_get_option( 'test_colorpicker' ); //this is the get option function provided by CMB2. See the whole function here: https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2-Snippet-Library/blob/master/options-and-settings-pages/theme-options-cmb.php
    restore_current_blog();

  printf( '<li role="presentation" class="%s"><a style="border-color:%s" href="%s">%s</a></li>', $mclass , $mycolor , 'http://'.$site['domain'].$site['path'], $details->blogname );
}
```

Can anyone help me out or maybe point me to a different solution to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble upon this in the future, this was actually answered by the [CMB2](http://cmb2.io/) author himself, [Michael Beckwith](http://michaelbox.net/):

```
$sites = wp_get_sites();
$current_site = get_current_blog_id();

foreach ($sites as $site) {
  $details = get_blog_details($site['blog_id']);
  $zSite = $details->blog_id;
  $mycolor = '';
  $mclass = '';

    if( $current_site == $zSite ) {
        $mclass = 'active';
    }

    switch_to_blog( $site[ 'blog_id' ] );
        $mycolor = get_option( 'myprefix_options' ); // here's the updated code
        $mycolor = $mycolor['test_colorpicker']; // here's the updated code
    restore_current_blog();

  printf( '<li role="presentation" class="%s"><a style="border-color:%s" href="%s">%s</a></li>', $mclass , $mycolor , 'http://'.$site['domain'].$site['path'], $details->blogname );
}
```

According to Michael:

> I believe the issue is stemming from the myprefix_admin() function, in the end. It's creating what's known as a singleton, which means only one instance of an object will exist at a given time. It's being run right away, and any time you do a call with myprefix_admin() afterwards will reference that first object. This includes inside foreach loops like what you're trying to do above.
>
> ...what we do is simply fetch the entire option, and then pluck out just the part we need, in this case the color picker value.

Thanks again CMB2's Michael Beckwith.